# Why can I no longer easily navigate inside of this mesh?

Tags: 3d-view

While originally modeling a mesh, I was able to easily re-orient my view to inside of the mesh.  In the process, I made the following changes:

- made the mesh completely hollow (removed some extraneous faces from the inside)
- added texture

Now I can't seem to navigate or zoom into the mesh like I was doing earlier.  All I can do is get ridiculously close to the outer surface.  Even in wireframe mode, I either can't do this or it seems as if everything is zoomed in much too close to do anything productive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're likely in Orthographic view, rather than Perspective View. Press <kbd>5</kbd> on your numeric keypad to toggle between the two.

If for some reason you want to stay in orthographic view and still see the inside of the mesh.

Some options:

- Hide faces that obscure the interior.
- Use mask modifier on meshes to mask out some geometry.
- Use view-clipping feature (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)
- Invert the normals of your mesh (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) and enable *backface culling* in *3D view > Properties*

Comment: Added some alternative methods incase users want to stay in ortho mode.

Answer (score -1):

You are in Orthographic View, just Press "5" to switch to Perspective View, now you can zoom to the inside of the object.

Comment: why add the same thing the other answer already says?